# Configure Reporting Services on SharePoint backend SQL server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, front-end

So currently I have an Integration mode installation of Reporting Services on my SharePoint backend SQL server, however this cannot be configured because the SharePoint backend SQL server must be configured as a SharePoint WFE, but I am unsure of how to do this. Can anyone help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are installing in the integrated mode you need to install it on one of the Sharepoint Servers. (either existing one or you need to provision a new one, if it is prod probably second option will be applicable) 
Check this article for steps: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261752.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are configuring a report server to run in SharePoint integrated mode in a SharePoint farm, the report server needs the SharePoint object model installed. The object model can be installed on the report server by installing front-end Web server components of a SharePoint product on the report server computer.

[How to: Install a SharePoint Web Front-end on a Report Server Computer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905869%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)